# Values of a wav file

Tags: c, audio, wav, libsndfile

In C, I am using the Libsndfile library to help me read the values of a wav file so that I can do some computations to them after. Although, when I get the output of the file, I am not sure what these numbers mean. Why are the numbers in the millions? At first I thought it was Hz, but it did not make sense in my mind. The information regarding the wav file can be seen below. Under that, I am using the function sf_read_int() to write the values into memory.

**What does sf_read_int() do?** This was obtained from the api documentation of libsndfile:

- The file write items functions write the data in the array pointed to by ptr to the file. The items parameter must be an integer product of the number of channels or an error will occur.

[image]

[image: Suspected values of the wav file]

I decided to plot some of these huge values on a graph, and it looks very similar to what the wav file should look like (If I imported into audacity and zoomed in on a specific location, I would see this). Note that the values shown are not the same values on the graph, I sampled the values at a random point in time. **So I guess the real question is, why are these values so big (in the millions)? And what do they represent? (Are they bytes?)**

[image]

Comment: What sample format does the file contain?  They might be floats?

Comment: I'll be honest with you, I have no idea how to check that. I converted a simple mp3 to a wav file online and used that as the file. Although, when I try sf_read_float(), my output is all 0's.

Comment: http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/

Comment: You need to look at the header of the wave file to determine the sample format. From [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV): *"The format chunk includes information such as the sample encoding, number of bits per channel, the number of channels, the sample rate."* Values in the millions indicate that the samples are 24 bits (or at least your software thinks they're 24 bits).

Comment: I thought SF_INFO had all those properties. Most of the values you listed have been outputted on the first picture. I tried getting the format as well, but I retrieved 65538

Comment: The most important one, number of bits per sample, was not shown. You can sort of guess it based on the file size. What's your file size in bytes?

Comment: It's 2,506,830 bytes.

Comment: Hmm, the `num_items` is 17,254,656 and the file size is 2,506,830. The only way that can happen is if the file is compressed, e.g. using MP3 compression. I can't help you with that. The whole point of a WAV file is that it's uncompressed (usually) and therefore easy to read.

Comment: I think there was an error on that part. I recomputed the values and got num_items to be 1253376. I'll update the image again. Turns out multiplying that value by two is almost the file size.

Comment: Samples are scaled to the size of the integer with which they are represented. The values represent the density of air molecules at the recording point at each slice of time. They are not in any particular unit of measurement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `limits.h` you can probably find two such definitions (among other stuff):

```
#define INT_MAX 0x7FFFFFFF
#define INT_MIN 0x80000000
```

which correspond to the decimal range between  -2147483648 and 2147483647.

**Libsndfile manual** says:

```
sf_count_t  sf_read_int(SNDFILE *sndfile, int *ptr, sf_count_t items);
```

i.e., reads sound file content into **integer** values pointed to by `int *ptr`. Whichever value falls between `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` is a legitimate value. In `libsndfile API` the data type used by the calling program and the data format of the file do not need to be the same.

Please also observe there's no such thing as "frequency" in a sound file. Linear PCM files only consist of **raw** sample data preceded by a header, whereas "frequency" is a mathematical abstraction or analysis result.

This might be of your interest:

> When converting between integer PCM formats of differing size (e.g. using sf_read_int() to read a 16 bit PCM encoded WAV file) libsndfile obeys one simple rule:
>
> Whenever integer data is moved from one sized container to another sized container, the most significant bit in the source container will become the most significant bit in the destination container.

Be sure to thoroughly read the manual, especially when it is clearly written.